# How do I reorder columns in MySQL Query Editor?

Tags: mysql

I want to move column `OtherSupport` below `Amount2` ... is there an easy way to do this?

[image: MySQL Query Editor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not the first one to ask. Here's the [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12064).

Either do it using SQL or use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

Answer (score 7):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY OtherSupport VARCHAR(50) AFTER Amount2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I have a general solution for mysql by sql query

**ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN misplaced_column Column-definition AFTER other_column;**
Here in *Column-definition* is full column definition. To see the column definition if you are using *phpmyadmin* click on structure tab. Then click on change link on desired column. Then withour modifyig any things click save. It will show you the sql. Copy the sql and just add *AFTER other_column* at the end. It will be all.

If you like to bring the *misplaced_column* to the first position then
**ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN misplaced_column Column-definition FIRST;**

Comment: Thanks for this. There's a "Move Columns" option under the "Structure" view in in phpMyAdmin. Even though it works well (in a draggable overlay), it's a big shame you have no opportunity to see the actual SQL executed. Elsewhere you could have a "Preview SQL" option which would come in handy if you need to run the query directly.