# How can I change column order through mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to reorder column order through query,
[How do I reorder columns in MySQL Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739644/how-do-i-reorder-columns-in-mysql-query-editor),

I just want to know is there any other (simpler) way to do this directly through MySQL workbench.

Comment: Right click on the table.select alter table and in the columns box drag the column to it's new location.

Comment: i was not able to drop the box to any other position, am i doing something wrong

Comment: Here's a link for you to work through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html

Answer (score 12):

Right-click the column and choose `Move Up` or `Move Down`. Dragging does not work in MySQL Workbench 6.3.

[image]

P.Salmon commented with a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html) that has more detail.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Alter Table
- Just move column with your mouse to the position you want (Do not select it before this action)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should get column definition by using **show create Table** then I think **Modify** should work

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName MODIFY bar bartype AFTER baz;
```

Hope it will help

Comment: yes, this could be an alternate solution but i have found my answer. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers point out, we need open Alter Table first. On workbench 8.0, right click table, then click 'Alter table'

[Image to show how to open Alter Table on Workbench 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbmZJ.png)

The SQL I got from moving a column is as follows with "CHANGE COLUMN" keywords.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_database`.`your_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `column_a` `column_a` VARCHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'this is comment' AFTER `colum_b`;
```